# epson code misread as string output

Tags: delphi, epson, delphi-10.2-tokyo

Printing using Epson codes in Delphi Tokyo.
Function PrintRawData (built in to Winapi.Winspool library) appears to misread codes like 'ESC C' or 'ESC @' and prints 'C' and '@' instead of the prompts associated with said codes (Select page length & Initialise Printer).

```
procedure TFrmPrint.PageLen(hPrn : THandle); // Page length in Inches
var
  Commalist     :       Array[1..20] of SmallInt;
  istart, icomma, i   :   SmallInt;
  ss, cr   :   UTF8String;
  def   :   UTF8String;
  Data  :   Array [0..255] of AnsiChar;
begin
  ss := '';
  cr := '  ';
  cr[1] := #13; cr[2] := #10;

  if not DM2.Q_PRNGen.Locate('PrAction','PAGELENIN',[loCaseInsensitive]) then
  begin
    ShowMessage('PAGELENIN Action not coded for Printer');
    exit;
  end;
  ss := Trim(DM2.Q_PRNGen.Fields.FieldByName('ESCCODE').AsString);

  icomma := 0;
  istart := 1;
  for i:=1 to Length(ss) do
  begin
    if ss[i] = ',' then
    begin
      inc(icomma);
      Commalist[icomma] := StrToIntDef(Copy(ss,istart,i-istart),0);
      istart := i + 1;
    end;
  end;
  inc(icomma);
  i := Length(ss);
  Commalist[icomma] := StrToIntDef(Copy(ss,istart,i-istart+1),0);

  def := '';
  for i:=1 to icomma do
  begin
    def := def + ' ';
    def[i] := AnsiChar(CommaList[i]);
//    def := Def + IntToHex(CommaList[i],1);

  end;

//  ss := def + cr;
  ss := def;
  for i:=1 to Length(ss) do Data[i-1] := AnsiChar(ss[i]);
  if frmPrint.PrintRawData(hPrn,@Data,Length(ss)) < 0 then
  begin
    ShowMessage('PrintRawData Failed');
    frmPrint.EndRawPrintPage(hPrn);
    frmPrint.EndRawPrintJob(hPrn);
    exit;
  end;
end;
```

It is under my assumption that the error lies within PrintRawData.
PrintRawData is listed here:

```
function TFrmPrint.PrintRawData(hPrn : THandle; Buffer : pointer;  NumBytes : SpoolInt) : integer;
var
  BytesWritten : DWORD;
begin
  if NumBytes = 0 then
  begin
    Result := 1;
    exit;
  end;
  if not WritePrinter(hPrn, Buffer, NumBytes, BytesWritten) then
  begin
     Result := -1;
     exit;
  end;
  if NumBytes <> BytesWritten then
  begin
    Result := -1;
    exit;
  end;
  Result := 1;
end;
```

Comment: You appear to have implemented your own PrintRawData (because you call frmPrint.PrintRawData). Can we see it, please?

Comment: Please edit your question. The code is unreadable in the comments (and will probably be missed anyway).

Comment: Edited. Please review.

Comment: So, I'm guessing that in the database has fields like '27,67' (for ESC C) and '27, 64' (for ESC @). 'Correct?

Comment: You are using WritePrinter not the windows API PrintRawData in your custom procedure PrintRawData.

Comment: @KenWhite can you please elaborate on where i can access the windows winspool version?

Comment: Actually, you're probably looking for the GDI function [`Escape()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd162701(v=vs.85).aspx) instead. Using the `PASSTHROUGH` flag, you can send unfiltered printer command's to the printer's HDC (Canvas.Handle). Also see [this page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff686805(v=vs.85).aspx) for more modern printer support.